# Trying to update a document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I would like to update a document (put the username 'toto' on the model id 1). The problem is, anything happen from the update() call (like if the application was waiting for something), and i don't go to the update callback.

I don't understand what happend, here is the code:

```
UserSchema : {
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
};

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(UserSchema);
UserSchema
        .virtual('id')
        .get(function(){
            return this.get('_id');
        }).set(function(id){
            return this.set('_id', id);
        });    

var User = db.model('User', UserSchema);
var Entity = new User();

Entity.update({ _id: 1 }, { username: 'toto'}, null, function(error, numAffected){
    if (error){
        console.log("|-->Error Query trying to update model");
    }else{
        console.log("|-->Update model succeed");
    }
});
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was to instanciate a Use and `update()` on its instance instead apply the `update()` call to the UserSchema.